# When following a referral for an A record in an DNS iterative query, should the next question be an A type or NS type?

Tags: dns

For example: I want to look up the A record for `www.ardainc.org`.

I query the root servers and get back an answer with a referral to the `.org` servers.

When I query the `.org` server next, do I send the same question (an A record for `www.ardainc.org`) or do I ask now instead for the NS records for the domain name?

Empirically, asking for A records all the way down seems to always work, but I [keep](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/dns-records-an-introduction/#dns-resolution) [hearing](https://www.digitalpacific.com.au/blog/ns-dns-records/) that resolvers first look up the name servers for a domain, and then ask for the actual records they want. The RFCs do not seem to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send always the same question, because irrespective of the `QTYPE` the authoritative nameserver will give you a referral to the proper nameservers, so you get "automatically" the NS records in the `AUTHORITY` section.

See the generic algorithm in RFC1034 section 4.3.2.
It is not clear from where you hint "but I keep hearing that you need to check NS records."

You can easily reproduce it manually, summarized for your case:

### Step 1

`dig www.ardainc.org A @a.root-servers.net` gives:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47905
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 13

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
org.            2d IN NS d0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            2d IN NS a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            2d IN NS c0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            2d IN NS a2.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            2d IN NS b0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            2d IN NS b2.org.afilias-nst.org.
```

### Step 2

We pick any one to go further:

`dig www.ardainc.org A @b2.org.afilias-nst.org.` gives:

```
; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39247
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ardainc.org.        1d IN NS ns.josh.com.
ardainc.org.        1d IN NS ns2.josh.com.
```

### Step 3

Same step as previous:

`dig www.ardainc.org A @ns2.josh.com.` gives:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23030
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1


;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ardainc.org.    3m8s IN CNAME web.josh.com.
web.josh.com.       5m IN CNAME aws.josh.com.
aws.josh.com.       1m IN A 18.217.156.232
```

We got our answer, the resolution stops there. Note that we did three `A` queries, never a `NS` one.

If you do `dig +trace` you will see the same thing,

(of course beneath what you see more happens, because when you do `@ns2.josh.com.`, `dig` has first to resolve this name to find the IP address, so more `A` and `AAAA` queries)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. So if I run my own DNS servers and I sync them using using some out-of-band method, should I ever see any requests for `NS` type records (except for those coming from humans who think you need to check the `NS` records)?

Comment: @bigjosh `NS` records are needed to find the zone cuts and hence are needed if you want QNAME minimization and proper DNSSEC support. See  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7816#appendix-A for the algorithm that happens and how `NS` records are then used.

Comment: Ah, I would not have thought of the QNAME minimization and DNSSEC complications. These likely explain the NS record requests I see on my DNS servers. Thanks!